# EF 4.2 Create a relation one-to-one without relationship on the Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, one-to-one

I need to rewrite a classic ASP to C#.NET and the system have 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
Table1
{
   [Key]
   public string WebRef {get;set;}
   ....
}
```

Table 2:

```
 Table2
{
  [Key]
  public string WebRef{get;set;}
  [Key]
  public int sequence{get;set;}
   .....
}
```

On the SQL Server they don't have any relation but It's one-to-one relationship.

Question: Is it possible to create a relationship using EF 4.2?

I need to put the table 2 inside the model of table 1 to be like:

```
Table1
{
   [Key]
   public string WebRef {get;set;}
   ....
   public Table2 table2{get;set}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I Did and I received an error:
`Invalid column name 'Table2_WebRef'.`
`Invalid column name 'Table2_sequence'.`
I tried to map the configuration but I still this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOptions.Identity)]
    public int Table1ID{get;set;}

}

public class Table2
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOptions.Identity)]
     public int Table2ID{get;set;}

     [ForeignKey("Table1")]
     public int Table1ID {get;set;}

     public virtual Table1 Table1 {get; set;}

}
```

This is a One-to-N relationship, to make a One-to-One relationship, you need to set Table1ID of Table2 as UniqueKey by SQLSERVER, because EF CodeFirst does not support unique keys...

Comment: Will I need to create another Primary key in the Database? Is there no other way?

Comment: Every table needs a PrimaryKey... In Table2 you need a PrimaryKey and a UniqueKey that also is a ForeingKey of Table1, is the only way to do a One-to-One relationship.

EF CodeFirst does not support UniqueKeys, so you need to set Table1ID of Table2 as uniquekey by sqlserver.

This is the only way that I know.

Comment: Both tables have primary key but they are strings. And I don't know if I can change the database because of the Classic ASP that already exists.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to put Table2 inside Table1, right ? To do that you need to create a NavigationProperty in Table1 (public virtual Table2 MyNagationProperty { get; set; }, like I did in the answer.

Comment: After try a little more I discovered that I can set my Table2 as a Collection: `public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2{get;set;}` and this is working. I don't understand why, but at least I don't need to change the database for a while.

Comment: Ok, but this is One-to-N relationship. Table1 has N Table2... I thought you wanted a One-to-One relationship...